# Random walk in candy shop

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-walk

At a candy counter there are $2 \cdot n$ children waiting to buy candy boxes, $n$ of them have only £1 coins and the other $n$ children have only £2 coins. Initially, the candy shop has no change. If each children buys one £1 candy box, what is the probability that all children are capable of buying their candy boxes without changing their queuing order? Can somebody present a random walk solution please?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number and search for the word "mountain." (Each upstroke is a child with a 1 pound coin; each downstroke is a child with a 2 pound coin. The mountain range represents the number of 1 pound coins in the shop's till as the children make their purchases.)

Comment: Very related: [Cashier has no change... catalan numbers.. probability question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990747/cashier-has-no-change-catalan-numbers-probability-question)

Comment: This is essentially a variant of [Bertrand’s ballot problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_ballot_theorem#Variant:_ties_allowed).

Comment: Thank you! Do you know any similar/related questions?