# How to solve this question regarding permutations and combinations?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have the following question:

> The price of a zoo ticket is $1$Dollar , If $n$ number of people give the ticket vendor $1$ Dollar and $m$ number of people give the vendor $2$ Dollars, and in the beginning the vendor does not have any change to return, in how many ways can the people stand such that the line does not choke.

I first thought that the first person must have a $1$Dollar and the total number of people having $1$ Dollar must be more than or equal to the total number of people having $2$ Dollars, in front of a person. But this didn’t get me anywhere, can anyone please help

Comment: Consider the amount of money (change) in the register. It must stay non-negative ... Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990747/cashier-has-no-change-catalan-numbers-probability-question) is a duplicate (using different numbers).